# How to fill html form using web browser control

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6

In VB6 classical, we could do:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
     WebBrowser1.Navigate2 "http://yourSite.com"
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
With Webbrowser1
     .Document.All("fieldName").Value = "some value"
     'click the button
     .Document.All("fieldName").Click
End With

End Sub
```

However in VB.Net, we get error that there is no `Value` property, so I tried:

```
  With wb
     ' fill From field
     .Document.All("fieldName").SetAttribute("Value", strFrom)
     ' click the button now
     .Document.All("fieldName").RaiseEvent("Click")
  End With
```

But even that generates an error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

On line:

```
.Document.All("fieldName").SetAttribute("Value", strFrom)
```

How to do same thing in VB.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember the old VB6 way, if you want to invoke a HTML Element's click event in VB.Net code:

```
Private Function ClickSubmitButton()

Dim theButton As HtmlElement

Try

' Link the ID from the web form to the Button var
theButton = webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("loginbutton")

' Now do the actual click.
theButton.InvokeMember("click")
Return True

Catch ex As Exception

Return False

End Try

End Function
```

With setting attributes, try this as an example (off the top of my head):

```
Dim textArea = webBrowser1.Document.All("foo")
If textArea <> Nothing Then
textArea.InnerText = "This is a test"
End IF
```