# VB.NET throwing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

Why do I get this Exception?

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

With:

```
wb.Document.GetElementById("formfieldv1").InnerText = "some value"
```

Where `wb` is the name of the `WebBrowser` control.

Here is all the code:

```
Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
Dim strFrom As String = txtFrom.Text
Dim strTo As String = txtTo.Text
Dim strMsg As String = txtMsg.Text
wb.Document.GetElementById("formfieldv1").InnerText = strFrom ' strFrom fills fine
End Sub
```

---

**Update**

As suggested in comments I modified code like this:

```
  Dim doc = wb.Document

  If (doc Is Nothing) Then
     MsgBox("doc is nothing")
  End If


  Dim el = wb.Document.GetElementById("formfieldv1")

  If (el Is Nothing) Then
     MsgBox("el is nothing")
  Else
     el.InnerText = strFrom
  End If
```

With that I am getting `el is nothing`. How do I solve this now ?

---

Alternatively if you guys can help me out with this that will solve my problem too:

[How to fill html form using web browser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767434/how-to-fill-html-form-using-web-browser-control)

Comment: Either `wb` is `Nothing`, the `Document` is `Nothing`, or a `formfieldv1` element does not exist in the document.

Comment: Break it down in steps. Either `Document` or the result of `GetElementById()` is null.

Comment: @Oded: The `wb` is dropped on form and I can see its members when typing it. Also `formfieldv1` is there as can be seen here freesmscraze.com for `From` field

Comment: As @Henk suggested, you should break down each part of that line - assign `wb.Document` to a variable. Then call `GetElementById` on that, assigning the result to an element, then set `InnerText` on this variable. One of these will be `Nothing`.

Comment: @Oded: The `el` here turns `Nothing`: `Dim el = wb.Document.GetElementById("formfieldv1")` How do I solve this plz ?

Comment: Make sure there is indeed an element with id `formfieldv1` in the loaded document.

Comment: @Oded: There is one for sure as can be seen in `From` field here: http://www.freesmscraze.com/

Comment: Well either there's no element with an id of formfieldv1, is it spelled correctly (case ?). It's not there yet, or there never was one, and you just got  brain lock. You aren't the first and won't be the last to get that.

Comment: How do you _know_ that the document you see on that page is the same as you downloaded in the browser control? Are you _certain_ they are identical? That you are getting this error suggests that it isn't.

Comment: @Oded: Yes same document is loaded in web browser control and i can see it opening fine in it. I do it from load event of form: `wb.Navigate("freesmscraze.com")`

Comment: You are making the assumption that the document you see in a browser is the same that the control does.

Comment: @Oded: No i am not making an assumption, see it for yourself the page in web browser control: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=f2ce8c4. You would see same thing if you visited: www.freesmscraze.com

Comment: The form is in a frame, so you need that to be the document, not the url you provided. If you view source on that you won't see it. Have to select the frame by selecting that, and then you are in the right place.

Comment: I am curious as to why you are doing all this in VB rather than JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a great example of why it's good to break down operations into several lines, instead of trying to do many operations in one line, especially when null values can be returned.

If you take `wb.Document.GetElementById("formfieldv1").InnerText = "some value"`

and break it down into

```
var document = wb.Document;
var element = document.GetElementById("formfieldv1");
element.InnerText = "some value";
```

When the exception is thrown, it will be much more apparent what is failing.  It is also easier to inspect the result of each operation when stepping through code.  From a compilation standpoint, it will make no difference, it will ultimately be compiled down to the same IL.

I think there tends to be a natural desire to do as much as possible in a single line of code, but I think in many cases it hurts readability and debug-ability.

Comment: There was an iframe actually which i did not notice, thanks to Tony who spotted that in comments above. Thanks for your answer though.